How to find all the 16 different areas (with Ozawa's style) of Xevious (namco, 80's)?
Have you all the 16 different areas (of the style of the next image) of Xevious, or could you help me to find it on internet?

In the late 1990's I download the 16 areas of Xevious, as you can see in this scanned image

I downloaded it from http://max89.hp.infoseek.co.jp/namco/xevious/ (obsolete) what you can view now 2 of the areas (are8.gif and area10.gif) at https://web.archive.org/web/20000602041445/http://www.nemoto.ecei.tohoku.ac.jp:80/~ozawa/xevious/map/map.html
Note: I know about any other similar graphs but only part of the 16 have the ground enemies
http://www.thullen.com/xevious/maps/area01.html
